# Laravel - multiple controllers in single view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to code a simple event page. This page should display a particular event and it's features (including other info not relevant for the problem).

I've tried a couple different approaches with no luck, this is the approach I feel like I might be closet to success with, any suggestions?

I can provide other extracts of code if you think the problem lies elsewhere but I think my problem lies within these 7 files.

The current error I have is "Property [features] does not exist on this collection instance." and point to the EventController show() function.. if anyone could help I'd greatly appreciate it.

web.php

```
Route::get('cards/{id}', 'CardController@show');
Route::get('event/{id}', 'EventController@show');
```

event.blade.php

```
<h1 class="big-title">
</h1>

<section id="events">
  @each('partials.event', $event, 'event')
</section>
```

(partials) event.blade.php

```
  <header>
    <h2 class="event-name fsb">
      {{ $event->name }}
    </h2>
  </header>
  <p class="event-description pdl1em">
    {{ $event->description }}
  </p>
  <ul class="event-dates pdl1em">
    <ul>
      @each('partials.features', $event_features, 'feature')
    </ul>
  </ul>
```

Event.php

```
class Event extends Authenticatable
{
    public function features() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\EventFeature');
    }
}
```

EventFeature.php

```
class EventFeature extends Authenticatable
{
    public function event() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Event');
    }
}
```

EventController

```
class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
      $event = DB::table('event')->where('id', $id)->get();
      return view('pages.event', ['event' => $event, 'features' => $event->features]);
    }
}
```

EventFeatureController

```
class EventFeatureController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
      $event_features = DB::table('event_features')->where('id', $id)->get();
      return view('pages.event', ['event' => $event_features->eventClass, 'features' => $event_features]);
    }

    public function list($event_id)
    {
      if (!Auth::check()) return redirect('/login');

      $event_features = DB::table('event_features')->where('event_id', $event_id)->orderBy('id')->get();
      return view('pages.event', ['event_features' => $event_features]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to retrieve a single item, use `find($id)` or `first()` to retrieve an instance of the model. When you call `get()` you get a collection of an array with the instances inside it.

When using `DB::table('events')` you dont get as a result an instance of the model, you get a generic object instance => you can't use Model class defined methods like relations and such. use the model directly instead `Event::where(...`

Change your method to

```
class EventController extends Controller
{
    public function show($id)
    {
      $event = Event::findOrFail($id);
      return view('pages.event', ['event' => $event, 'features' => $event->features]);
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, i'm getting this error when I use "::find":
**count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, App\Models\Event given**

Comment: @GuilhermeMoreira `::find()` returns a Single Model, or `null`; there should be no reason to use `count()` anywhere, but your original question doesn't have `count` anywhere in it. If you have a new problem, ask a new question; don't post it in a comment on an answer.